# Can the below function be improve?(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have the below function

```
public static List<DateTime> GetOnlyFridays(DateTime endDate, int weeks, bool isIncludeBaseDate)
{
    //Get only the fridays from the date range
    List<DateTime> dtlist = new List<DateTime>();

    List<DateTime> tempDtlist = (from dtFridays in GetDates(endDate, weeks)
                                 where dtFridays.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday
                                 select dtFridays).ToList();

    if (isIncludeBaseDate)
    {
        dtlist = tempDtlist.Skip(1).ToList();
        dtlist.Add(endDate);
    }
    else
    {
        dtlist = tempDtlist;
    }

    return dtlist;
}
```

What basically I am doing is getting the datelist using the **GetDates** function and then depending on the `isIncludeBaseDate bool value`(if true) skipping the last date and adding the `Base Date`

It is working fine but can this program can be improve?

I am using C#3.0 and Framework 3.5

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to initialise the `dtlist` - you never use that. I'd also move the .ToList() from the LINQ line down to the else case - that way you never build a list just to throw it away again immediately in the include-base-date case. But these aren't anything major.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing too many temporary list-conversions; you can keep all the work as a query until the very end, that way it'll only be evaluated once.

```
public static List<DateTime> GetOnlyFridays(DateTime endDate, int weeks, bool isIncludeBaseDate)
{
    var fridays = GetDates(endDate, weeks)
                    .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);
    if (isIncludeBaseDate)
    {
        fridays = fridays.Skip(1)
                         .Concat(new []{endDate});
    }
    return fridays.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert to a list immediately. For example, the following should work just as well, but without the need to convert the result to a list (it allows you to loop over them in a foreach loop, for example, without ever having to instantiate an entire list. If you pass in a large number for `weeks` that could be a big saving in terms of memory usage):

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetOnlyFridays(DateTime endDate, int weeks, bool isIncludeBaseDate)
{
    var fridays = from dtFridays in GetDates(endDate, weeks)
                  where dtFridays.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday
                  select dtFridays;

    if (isIncludeBaseDate)
    {
        return fridays.Skip(1);
    }
    return fridays;
}
```

Comment: His code also appends the endDate in the isIncludeBaseDate case - you'll want to .Union() that in too.

Comment: The GetDates function fetches the dates from 1 day prior..e.g. it the basedate is 03/26/2010, the Getdate() funciton will give the dates starting from 03/25/2010 onwards.. Henceforth I had to add teh base date explicitly

Comment: @Rup, oops, I missed that, yeah. As in tzaman's solution, `Concat` can be used to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would also try finding the closest friday at or before 'endDate', then for as many weeks we have, do a DateTime.AddDays(7); and of course take into consideration isIncludeBaseDate.